# Delphi: SW_HIDE doesn't work anymore?

Tags: delphi

I have to run some other application from my program and hide it's form. In Windows XP it was easy:

```
  ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'foo.exe', nil, nil,SW_HIDE);
```

But it seems that it doesn't work anymore in Vista and win7.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does not run at all, or runs but not hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, at least

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
```

appears to work as one would expect. I do not have a Windows XP machine available, but exactly what happened on XP? If i run

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe', nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
```

in Windows 7, a notepad.exe process is created, but no window is shown. I guess that the window is created but now shown, as is what one might expect, actually. You can probably show the window later on by using the FindWindow and ShowWindow functions.

**Update:**

I just confirmed my hypothesis:

```
  var
    h: hWnd;

  ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe', nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
  sleep(100);
  h := FindWindow(nil, 'Namnlös - Anteckningar');
  if IsWindow(h) then
    ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOW)
```

displays the newly created window (with title "Namnlös - Anteckningar", i.e. "New file - Notepad" in Swedish).

**Update 2:**

Notice that

- I could have used 'open' as verb instead of **nil**.
- My code does not work if I replace the full path of notepad.exe with simply 'notepad.exe'.

Comment: yes this is working on windows 7

This works too

ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'foo.exe', nil, nil,SW_HIDE);

Answer (score 1):

Not all applications respect the SW_... flags correctly in their startup info.